# Aerospike Hearbeat calls stuck in TIME_WAIT

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, aerospike

I'm trying to setup an Aerospike Cluster on GCP. I'm using Core OS and Docker to run the Aerospike daemon.

I've following configuration in `aerospike.conf` for `as-node-01`

```
    service {
        service-threads 10

    }               

    network {                

        service {
            address any
            port 3000
            access-address as-node-01
        }           
        fabric {
            address any
            port 3001

        }            
        info {
            address any
            port 3003
        }              
        heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            address as-node-01
            port 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-02 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-01 3002

        }         
    }


    logging {
        console { 
            context any info
        }
    }               


    namespace rte {       
    memory-size 4G           
        replication-factor 1     
        high-water-memory-pct 60 

        stop-writes-pct 90       
        default-ttl 0            

        storage-engine memory    
    }
```

and following for `as-node-02`

```
    service {
        service-threads 10

    }               

    network {                

        service {
            address any
            port 3000
            access-address as-node-02
        }           
        fabric {
            address any
            port 3001

        }            
        info {
            address any
            port 3003
        }              
        heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            address as-node-01
            port 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-01 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-02 3002

        }         
    }


    logging {
        console { 
            context any info
        }
    }               


    namespace rte {       
    memory-size 4G           
        replication-factor 1     
        high-water-memory-pct 60 

        stop-writes-pct 90       
        default-ttl 0            

        storage-engine memory    
    }
```

I'm using `aerospike:4.6.0.4` docker image with following command

```
docker run -d -v `pwd`:/opt/aerospike/etc --name aerospike -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -p 3002:3002 -p 3003:3003 aerospike asd --foreground --config-file /opt/aerospike/etc/aerospike.conf
```

When I start the daemon on both the nodes, I see following in log content.

```
Nov 02 2019 07:20:23 GMT: WARNING (socket): (socket.c:959) (repeated:67) Error while connecting socket to 10.160.0.14:3002
Nov 02 2019 07:20:23 GMT: WARNING (hb): (hb.c:4882) (repeated:67) could not create heartbeat connection to node {10.160.0.14:3002}
Nov 02 2019 07:20:23 GMT: WARNING (socket): (socket.c:900) (repeated:67) Error while connecting: 111 (Connection refused)
```

I then tried to see with `netstat` that what is wrong, and I see the heartbeat calls stuck in `TIME_WAIT` state.

```
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39890        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38662        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39998        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39878        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39716        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39252        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39872        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39776        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38796        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38668        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38844        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39668        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39120        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39138        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39174        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38740        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39614        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39000        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39318        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38982        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39584        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39420        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:38758        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39656        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39866        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39482        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39222        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 as-node-01.asia-so:3002 172.17.0.2:39818        TIME_WAIT
```

There are hundreds of these calls in `TIME_WAIT` state.

I'm unable to figure out why these calls are stuck in TIME_WAIT and aren't getting forwarded to docker container.

Comment: Looks like both your hb address bindings are pointing to address as-node-01. May want to use the name of the interface instead. ie: address eth0 or address ens01,or which ever interface name you want aerospike to bind to for heartbeat in the container.

Comment: That's a copy paste mistake. But I'll try to change it to eth0.

Comment: @lvolmar I changed network to host (`--net host`) for my docker container and things started working for me. 

I'm not really sure why port `3000` was working on the default bridge network and not `3002`.

Comment: Did changing it it to eth0 also helped? or was it he -net host change which would force the container to use your hosts interfaces

Comment: Better solution than --net host may be using an overlay network to communicate between physical nodes. Please see https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are running two containers on two different nodes.
and using node (host) names in the `aerospike.conf`.

```
heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            address as-node-01
            port 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-01 3002
            mesh-seed-address-port as-node-02 3002
}
```

- `address as-node-01` points to an interface which will not be accessible inside the container if the containers are not on the host network. That’s why `--network=host` worked for you.
- If you are not using `--net=host` then by default containers are on private network and cannot ping other hosts (nodes) or connect to containers on other hosts.

So to work with this, what you might need is an overlay network (for
   multi-host networking). You can then simply use the container’s
   private IP in aerospike `mesh` configuration.

You can try docker swarm. If not docker swarm, you might need to run an external key value store (like `consul` etc.) for discovery with the overlay network.

https://www.aerospike.com/docs/deploy_guides/docker/networking/index.html

https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay-standalone.swarm/

https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @SP Kesan said,

Looks like you were using the same address binding for both nodes pointing to as-node-01.(address as-node-01) best practice would be to use the interface name (ie: eth0, or eth1, etc) This should also work with overlay network and let you specify the interface name for the overlay network.

Please see:
https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/

If the containers were residing on the same host than only changing your address binding should help with the issue. Since your containers are on different hosts, you either can use an overlay network for inter-node communications, or you could use --net host and leverage the host's network interfaces.

```
        service {
            address any
            port 3000
            access-address as-node-01
        }           
     ...     
        heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            address as-node-01
            port 3002
```

and

```
 service {
            address any
            port 3000
            access-address as-node-02
        }           
...            
        heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            address as-node-01
            port 3002
```